# Xamarin StackLayout Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, label, stacklayout

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Hello"/>
    <Slider/> 
 </StackLayout>
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" >
   <Label Text="Hello" />
    <Slider />
</StackLayout>
```

Output of above two codes are same can anyone explain the differece between specifying the vertical and  horizontal options to stacklayout vs defining these properties at label ?

Comment: HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions determine how an element is positioned within it's parent container

Comment: So how does label is positioned in center in both of the  above cases .  I think in second case stacklayout have these properties so  how does label get centred.

Comment: it you want the Label centered within it's parent you place the properties on the Label

Comment: But the output of both the cases are same. After setting up the horizontal and vertical options property in stacklayout label also get centers.

Comment: most likely because the parent container is not large enough for the alignment to matter.  By default a StackLayout will only be as big as needed to contain it's children.  If you want the StackLayout to fill it's own parent, you need to use "FillAndExpand".  The options are very well documented - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As jason mentioned , `LayoutOptions` only apply to the view/layout ,relative to its  parent .

In your case `HorizontalOptions="Center"` works for the `Label` and `StackLayout` , it is totally different .

For the first scenario , `Label`  locates in center of the outer stacklayout .

For the second scenario, `StackLayout` locates in center of the outer layout(here I use StackLayout for test).

Please check the following screenshot to clarify the differences.

[image]